# Push Button Probabilities

Tags: code-golf, math

## The Challenge

The challenge is that I have a standard mechanical push button lock and you need to find out every possible code that could unlock it.

With a standard mechanical push button lock you have all single digit numerals and sometimes a few letters.
With this specific push button lock there are specific rules.

**Rules**

- The buttons available to press are as follows :
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, X, Y, Z
- Only 4 button presses are allowed (Length of the push button code has to be 4 characters long)
- No button can be pressed twice (Therefore no doubles such as 1232 as you can't press 2 twice and the same goes for the letters)
- The order of the buttons is irrelevant and they can be pressed in any order. (This means the code 1560 is the same as 5610 and are both the same combination in the case of this specific lock and so only one should be recorded as a possible entry)

You have completed the challenge when your code compiles and does the following on seperate lines.

- It follows the rules.
- Print every entry that is not repeated.
- Print the probability of pressing 4 buttons within the rules and the chance of picking a correct combination.

This is Code-Golf so the shortest answer wins.

Comment: This seems a bit dull, consider making the challenge more general. You could also post it in teh [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xiv?cb=1) first for some feedback.

Comment: Ah. I was looking for something like a rules or regulations for codegolf and I couldn't see one. Now I realise that it was in front of me the whole time. I'll give that a try first.

Comment: I just tried to add it to the Sandbox however I don't have 5 reputation in Codegolf so I am unable to do so.

Comment: It is admittedly a bit of a catch 22, try and answer an easy question to get some rep, on PPCG it's considered harder to ask a good question than to answer a question.

Comment: So you just want us to iterate/print all [13 choose 4](https://www.google.com/search?q=13+choose+4&oq=13+choose+4) combinations? At that point, the probability for a single guess is 1/C(13,4), or 1/715.

Comment: @crystalwolf upvoted your question. Now you have > 5 reputation